# facing issue while putting multiple selection choice

Tags: python

```
guess = input("Enter the game Y/N : ")
bird = ["parrot", "pigeon", "sparrow", "bat"]
if guess.lower() == 'y':
    print("Guess the correct bird name parrot, pigeon, sparrow, bat : ")
    bird_input = input("Enter the bird name : ")
    if bird_input in bird:
        if bird_input == "bat":
          print("guess is correct.")
        elif bird_input == "sparrow":
          print("Yes, you are near.")
          bird = input("Enter the bird name : ")
        elif bird_input == "parrot":
          print("Almost near")
          bird = input("Enter the bird name : ")
        elif bird_input == "pigeon":
          print("you tried a lot!!")
          bird = input("Enter the bird name : ")
    else:
        print("Invalid selection.")
elif guess.lower() == 'n':
        print("Not intersted today!!")
else:
    print("Wrong selection")
print("Good luck!!")
```

facing issue to add multiple choice, i wants to give user to play 3 chance after that it will be out from game. but i don't know where i am doing mistake.

Comment: Your mistake is you forgot to put the query code in a loop.

Comment: thanks to give your response, i applied @TomKarzes